# Electron-Angular: Running Karma errors because of undefined ipcRenderer inside angular component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, electron, karma-jasmine, ipcrenderer

I have an Electron application that uses Angular (8) as a front end framework.
I am trying to implement unit testing but keep getting the following error when i start the test:

```
Chrome 77.0.3865 (Windows 10.0.0) FooterComponent should create FAILED
        TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
         ......
```

My spec file looks like this:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer.component';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { ElectronService } from '../services';


describe('FooterComponent', () => {
  let component: FooterComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FooterComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ 
        FooterComponent
      ],
      providers: [ElectronService ],
      imports: [
        TranslateModule.forRoot()
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooterComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();    
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    // ERROR IS HERE
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

});
```

Inside the Angular component i subscribe to an Electron event:

```
constructor(private electronService: ElectronService) {
   this.electronService.ipcRenderer.on('appVersion', (event, arg) => {
      this.appVersion = arg;
   });
}
```

This is what causes the test to fail, the ipcRenderer is undefined. Does anyone know how i can unit test an Angular component that has Electrons IPC used inside of it ?

The electronservice that is used in the component has been added to the providers inside the spec file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should mock the electron service and in your providers useClass: MockElectronService

```
class Channel {
  constructor(public name: string, public listener: () => {}) {}
}

export class Message {
  channel: string;
  params?: any[];
}

export class MockElectronService {
  channelSource = new Subject<Message>();

  private channels: Channel[] = [];

  ipcRenderer = {
    on: (name: string, listener: () => {}) => {
      this.channels.push(new Channel(name, listener));
    },
    once: (name: string, listener: () => {}) => {
      this.channels.push(new Channel(name, listener));
    },
    send: (channel: string, args: string) => {}
  };

  constructor() {
    this.channelSource.subscribe(msg => {
      this.channels.find(channel => channel.name === msg.channel).listener();
    });
  }
}
```